# ChromeのWebDriverのダウンロードディレクトリについて

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

ChromeのWebDriverでスクレイピングをしています。

スクレイピングでダウンロードしたファイルを保存する為に `ChromeOptions` で`download.default_directory` にディレクトリ名を指定しますが、作成されたディレクトリが以下のようになってしまい、のちのファイルの書き込みを行うメソッドを使った際に権限がない為、エラーになってしてしまいます。どうすれば解決しますか？

```
drwx------  3       1000       1000   4096 Oct 23 21:40
```

Comment: 保存先はコードの実行時に都度作成しなければいけないのでしょうか？あらかじめ適切に権限も設定されたディレクトリを指定すればよさそうな気がします。

Comment: @cubick さんコメントのように、これ [selenium/standalone-chrome-debug can't download files#548#issuecomment-346073488](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/548#issuecomment-346073488) と同様の現象でしょうか。selenium/chromedriverでフォルダを作るとrootパーミッションになるとか。事前に作ってパーミッションを変えておけばOKとか。

Comment: @cubick @kunif さんご回答ありがとうございます。あらかじめディレクトリを作成することでディレクトリ自体の権限は変えられましたが、スクレイピングでその中にダウンロードしてくるファイルの権限が、```-r-- 1 1000 1000 2378```となり、system関数経由のchmodメソッドで書き換えようと```system('chmod 777 '.$filepath, $result);```を試すも権限の変更ができません。他にPHPにおいてダウンロードされたファイルの権限の変更を行う、またはファイルのダウンロードを行う前にドライバー側でそれを設定する方法はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: この辺の記事並みに [PHPでChromeを操作（クロール）](https://note.mu/743/n/n7367632b1e19), [Laravel+Duskでブラウザテスト](https://qiita.com/Masakiy99/items/59e7f850f6b1552b3acf), [ヘッドレスChrome - Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally](https://teratail.com/questions/151448) システム構成とかやっていることとかを詳しく追記すると、アドバイスや回答が得られやすいと思われます。

Comment: @kunif アドバイスありがとうございます。今後の参考にさせていただきます。今回の件に関しては、権限を変えるのではなく、PHPのtmpfile()を使い、一時的に作成したファイルに内容をコピーすることにして解決しました。